# I lost access to my e-mail and I can't log into my Steam account. How can I regain access?

Tags: steam

When I was trying to log into my Steam account, Steam wanted me to input the Steam Guard Code, so I checked my phone and there was no code so I tried to change my password and try again, I did it and the password didn't even work, but the last one did, then I tried to disable Steam Guard Verification, after that I was logged out of Steam on both my phone and pc, so I tried to log back and Steam wanted me to input a verification code sent to me via my gmail, but my gmail account has been disabled a month ago and I can't get it back so... I have no idea what can I do now to get my Steam Account back and I'm really worried because I spent a lot of money on it.

Comment: What do you mean "my gmail has been disabled..."?

Comment: It says that my account is disabled when I'm trying to log in, you can search for this problem, I was looking for some help for a few hours I the only thing I can do probably is just wait. But I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Gmail Account is disabled, follow this link to try and reactivate: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40695?hl=en

If your Gmail account was deleted, then maybe try and reopen the account with the same email address. This will let you get emails for the Verification Code.

I am not sure what else you can do to sign in. Good luck, and hopefully Happy Gaming!

Comment: My account wasn't deleted it was only disabled and I'm waiting for more than a month for Google to analyze my request on reactivating my account

Comment: Then I think all you can do is wait for now. Sorry I can't help any further.

Answer (score 9):

Ok so I got my account back because I reminded myself that I had my phone number attached to it and it made it possible for me to change my Steam e-mail. Thanks for maybe a little but still some help. I hope anyone who has similar problems finds it useful.